# Maven archetypes for OpenJPA

Tags: jpa, maven, jpa-2.0, openjpa, archetypes

Greetings.

I'm just starting to explore Maven and I use m2eclipse as to use Maven in Eclipse.

I found that there is a hibernate-based archetype with 
Group Id: com.rfc.maven.archetypes and
Artifact Id: jpa-maven-archetype

Does anybody knows if there are archetypes for OpenJPA-based projected with test frameworks included?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anybody knows if there are archetypes for OpenJPA-based projected with test frameworks included?

Not to my knowledge. So my suggestion would be to use the jpa-maven-archetype and to tweak it for OpenJPA and JPA 2.0.

First, generate a project:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate \
  -DgroupId=com.stackoverflow \
  -DartifactId=Q4161012 \
  -DpackageName=com.stackoverflow.domain \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=com.rfc.maven.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=jpa-maven-archetype  \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 \
  -DremoteRepositories=http://maven.rodcoffin.com/repo \
  -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Then `cd` into the created directory and modify the `pom.xml` to replace Hibernate by OpenJPA artifacts, add the OpenJPA plugin for enhancement (I did a few other minor tweaks):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>Q4161012</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JPA Project</name>
  <properties>
    <openjpa.version>2.0.1</openjpa.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
      <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
      <version>${openjpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>com/stackoverflow/domain/**/*.class</includes>
          <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
          <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
          <!-- Pass additional properties to the Plugin here -->
          <toolProperties>
            <property>
              <name>directory</name>
              <value>otherdirectoryvalue</value>
            </property>
          </toolProperties>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enhancer</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>${openjpa.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then modify the `persistence.xml` for JPA 2.0 and add the OpenJPA specific properties:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="Q4161012"></persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="Q4161012-test"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.stackoverflow.domain.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:my-project-test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary"
                value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings"
                value="buildSchema(SchemaAction=add)"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And replace the following lines in `UserTest.java` (and clean up imports):

```
HibernateEntityManager em = (HibernateEntityManager) emf.createEntityManager();

DbUnitDataLoader loader = new DbUnitDataLoader(testData, em.getSession().connection());
```

By (OpenJPA doesn't support the `EntityManager#unwrap(Object)` from JPA 2.0 yet, see [OPENJPA-1803](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1803), so you have to use OpenJPA specific classes):

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
OpenJPAEntityManager oem = OpenJPAPersistence.cast(em);
Connection conn = (Connection) oem.getConnection(); 
conn.setAutoCommit(true);

DbUnitDataLoader loader = new DbUnitDataLoader(testData, conn);
```

And run the test:

```
$ mvn clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info. please given me a minute to test it out.