# OpenJPA: How to get Maven archetype-like for OpenJPA now that rodcoffin.com is gone?

Tags: maven, openjpa

There is a **broken** JPA archetype in the Java Archetypes List
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List

I tried to follow the instructions at:
[Maven archetypes for OpenJPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161012/maven-archetypes-for-openjpa)

Please note that http://maven.rodcoffin.com/repo has been taken over by site squatters.
I don't believe it is possible to use that site to retrieve the maven archetype for OpenJPA.

Many thanks for reading.